# Trigger that updates the average from another table

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two tables: Product and Review. I'm trying to make a trigger that updates the product table(column:stars) when a new review is inserted. They are connected by product_id. I tried this code but I guess its not right.

Code:

```
create trigger update_stars after insert on Review for each row 
update Product
set stars=(select avg(stars) from Review where product_id=Product.product_id)
where product_id=new.product_id;
```

[image: ERD]

Comment: How is your code "not right"?

Comment: Just a thought: don't store the rating with the product

Answer (score 1, accepted):

for the sql code you could use an update based on a inner join eg:

```
update Product p
inner join (
  select product_id, avg(stars) avg_stars
  from Review
  group by product_id
) t on t.product_id = p.product_id
set stars=t.avg_stars
```